# Python: CrashingPython explanation

Tags: python

I have a code in Python that makes the python interpreter crash randomly. I have tried to isolate the source of the problem, but I am still investigating. While searching on the net for  problems that could make the interpreter crash, I stumble upon this:

```
def crash():
    '''\
    crash the Python interpreter...
    '''
    i = ctypes.c_char('a')
    j = ctypes.pointer(i)
    c = 0
    while True:
            j[c] = 'a'
            c += 1
    j
```

http://wiki.python.org/moin/CrashingPython

Since I am using Ctypes, I think that the problem could be related to the way the Ctypes is used. So I am trying to understand why that code could make Python interpreter crash. Understanding it would help investigate my problem in my Ctypes code.

Can anybody explain this?

Help would be appreciate.

Comment: You stumbled upon some random code sample that's DESIGNED to crash the interpreter. If you're calling a method named `crash` you deserve what you get. Otherwise I doubt this is in any way related. Please post your actual code and not some tangential finding.

Comment: Since I know how to read, I know that this code IS designed to crash! My question was "How can this code make Python crash?" If I new where the problem is in my code, I would have posted it. I can't see why I deserve to be dragged in the mud for this.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realize that you were specifically asking about that. You may want to reword your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: You are right. My question leads to confusion. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It makes a pointer to memory that's likely to be unwritable, and writes to it.

The numerical value of `a` is very small, and very low memory addresses are typically not writable, causing a crash when you try to write to them.

Should the initial write succeed, it keeps trying successive addresses until it finds one that isn't writable.  Not all memory addresses are writable, so it's bound to crash eventually.

(Why it doesn't simply start at address zero I don't know - that's a bit odd.  Perhaps ctypes explicitly protects against that?)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that there you're writing to memory locations indefinitely. So it will come the time when the memory accessed will be unwritable and the program will crash.